# Query Local Postgres Database Over the Internet

Tags: postgresql

I have a web app I have been designing, but I have a very large locally stored PostgreSQL database on my computer. Given the size of this database, I would rather not store the data on my Cloud Postgres database. Is there anyway I can make it so my web app can access this database occasionally as needed?

I am running this local database on my Macbook and would only need it to be accessible when I am accessing my web app through my Mac.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You can do it but you need to spend time reading [Connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html), [Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) and [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). Failure to do so will have you back here looking for help with a hacked database.